# Outer Class can have how many inner class(es)

Tags: apex

In Apex, how many inner classes can an outer class have?

Comment: Welcome to SFSE! Please take the [tour] and read [ask]. I don't think there's any practical limit here, but I doubt there's documentation to back that up. This question, though, gives me an [X-Y Problem](http://xyproblem.info) vibe. I get the feeling that you either have a class with a bunch of inner classes and are running into an issue, or are trying to solve a problem and think that using a bunch of inner classes is the answer. Either way, the best way to get help from this community is to provide us with lots of details. What is your problem? How are you trying to solve it?

Comment: If you're getting an error message, providing the full error message, verbatim, really helps. The more relevant detail you can give us, the better we'll be able to understand your situation. Ultimately, that should end up getting you more useful and accurate answers.

Comment: And, for what it's worth, I've personally had somewhere between 12 - 36 inner classes contained in a single outer class (mostly just to help deserialize payloads from an external system). Haven't really counted the exact number.

Answer (score 11):

In the name of science, I attempted to save a class with programmatically generated inner classes that looked like the following:

```
public with sharing class Demo
{
    public class Inner0 { }
    public class Inner1 { }
    public class Inner2 { }
    public class Inner3 { }
    // ...
}
```

I kept expanding this pattern until I ran into an error. Adding 1000 at a time, it worked until I hit `InnerClass7000`, at which point I hit a generic compile fail:

> An unexpected error occurred

I walked it back until I found the exact maximum number of classes where I would not hit this error, and it is 6663. I was kind of hoping it would be 6666, but alas.

**Compiles:**

```
public with sharing class Demo
{
    // ...
    public class Inner6661 { }
    public class Inner6662 { }
    public class Inner6663 { }
}
```

**Does not compile:**

```
public with sharing class Demo
{
    // ...
    public class Inner6662 { }
    public class Inner6663 { }
    public class Inner6664 { }
}
```

---

If you are inquiring about how deeply nested inner classes can be, it is capped at one level.

```
public class Outer
{
    public class Inner
    {
        public class TooDeep
        {
            // not allowed
        }
    }
}
```

See also, [Apex Class Definition](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_defining.htm) (emphasis mine):

> In Apex, you can define top-level classes (also called outer classes) as well as inner classes, that is, a class defined within another class. **You can only have inner classes one level deep.**

Comment: The unexpected error was interesting. I was guessing you could go *much* higher... but alas.

Comment: Yeah if I had to guess, I too would have expected a higher number.

Answer (score 3):

The language spec doesn't say, so in theory, you could have 111,535 inner classes before you got a "class too large" error for exceeding 1,000,000 characters. It appears that a compiler error limits you to an [actual value of 6,663](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/274001). In the "real world", having more than 5-10 classes should be a sign that you should probably refactor and/or extract some classes in other other classes or top-level classes. The exception to this rule of thumb would be automatically generated code, such as WSDL2Apex, or JSON2Apex.

Comment: Thanks all Appreciate it